# How can I capture the render process with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I want all screenshots and timestamps when page appearance changes so that I can replay the render process.

I tried capture screenshots every x seconds with `page.screenshot()`，but it seems like the screenshots have been delayed.